# Select events that are in more than 1 group from mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have a table called event that has a event_id and a group_id. An event can only be part of 1 group but a group can have multiple events. I have a list of event ids and I only want to return the events that are part of a group that has at least 1 event.

```
select event_id, group_id from event where event_id in (123, 456);
```

This query gives me the respective group_id for each event_id but how can I take that group_id and run a second query to get the count of events that are part of that group?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: If the group has the event in question, then the group automatically has at least 1 event.  Hence, all events in those groups meet that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to make a few assumptions about your database schema to answer this. It sounds like you want to use aggregation. I've assumed that you have another table called groups, and that the attributes are named accordingly.

```
SELECT group_id,COUNT(*) AS 'Count' FROM event AS E
INNER JOIN group AS G ON E.group_id = G.group_id
WHERE E.eventID IN (123,456)
GROUP BY group_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sub query,

Try this,

```
select group_id, count(event_id) from event where group_id in 
(select group_id from event where event_id in (123, 456)) group by group_id;
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: thank you this will return the group_id with the count but is there a way to return the event_ids that I passed that have groups with more than 1 event. So my end result should just be the filtered list of event_ids.

Comment: you have to modify your query,

Comment: select group_id,event_id,c from event e, (select group_id,count(event_id) c from event where group_id in( select group_id from event where event_id in(123,456)) group by group_id) a where e.group_id = a.event_id and e.event_id in (123,456);